# Планировщик задач для многопоточного приложения

Tags: многопоточность, планировщик-задач, планирование

Дали в университете одну задачу, но я не знаю как ее выполнить. Допустим у нас есть несколько потоков, которые параллельно выполняют задачи, которые им дает планировщик, при этом речь идет о batch scheduling, потоки при этом отличаются по мощности, поток 1 к примеру может выполнять операции со скоростью миллион операции в секунду, поток 2 со скоростью 2 миллиона операций в секунду. Нужно эффективно спланировать задачи для нескольких потоков так чтобы среднее время выполнения задач в системе было минимальным, при условии что нам известно сколько операций нужно для выполнения каждой задачи (задачи могут быть разные с разным временем выполнения). И да, у меня есть доступ к гуглу, просто после долгого поиска хоть каких-то алгоритмов планирования(SJF,SJN,FCFS итд), я находил только те которые позволяли спланировать последовательность выполнения задач для одного потока,но никак не для нескольких, есть ли такие алгоритмы которые позволяют эффективно распределить задачи для нескольких потоков?

Comment: Венгерский алгоритм?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант: если нужно минимизировать среднее время выполнения задачи - то самые быстрые задачи надо вперед ставить. Но так как потока два, то наверное, в момент когда один поток освобождается, надо брать из очереди или самую короткую задачу или следующую за ней (по объему работ) - в зависимости от того кто ее быстрее выполнит - текущий освободившийся поток или второй (еще занятый) поток (с учетом оставшегося времени работы второго потока). Ну если потоков больше - с учетом всех других потоков.
Это если неизвестны все задачи в очереди. 
А если они все известны - то можно  просто просчитать какая последовательность работ более выгодна.